# C#: How to convert BITMAP byte array to JPEG format?

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg, bmp

How can I convert a BITMAP in byte array format to JPEG format using .net 2.0?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What type of `byte[]` do you mean? The raw file-stream data? In which case, how about something like (using `System.Drawing.dll` in a client application):

```
    using(Image img = Image.FromFile("foo.bmp"))
    {
        img.Save("foo.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Or use `FromStream` with a `new MemoryStream(arr)` if you really do have a `byte[]`:

```
    byte[] raw = ...todo // File.ReadAllBytes("foo.bmp");
    using(Image img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(raw)))
    {
        img.Save("foo.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Comment: The second one was just what I was searching for.
I'm however writing into another MemoryStream rather than to file.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If it is just a buffer of raw pixel data, and not a complete image file(including headers etc., such as a JPEG) then you can't use Image.FromStream.

I think what you might be looking for is System.Drawing.Bitmap.LockBits, returning a System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageData; this provides access to reading and writing the image's pixels using a pointer to memory.

Answer (score -4):

```
public static Bitmap BytesToBitmap(byte[] byteArray)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
  {
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
    return img;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a bitmap. he wants a jpeg.

Comment: Correct, the code is not complete. But it returns a Bitmap, which you can later on save to a file in any format.... I guess this is my welcome to the Reputation Wars... My fault anyway.

Comment: @juanjo.arana but you have not given an answer to his question, just told him how to get a bitmap.