# Error" Parameter is not valid " while converting Bytes into Image

Tags: c#, .net, image, arrays, memorystream

I am converting bytes into an image but I get an error

> Parameter is not valid

I am pasting my code. Kindly check the code and suggested that was I am doing right or wrong.

```
Image arr1 = byteArrayToImage(Bytess);
```

This is the function.

```
public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
        if (null == byteArrayIn || byteArrayIn.Length == 0)
            return null;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        try
          {
            Process currentProcess1 = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
          }
        catch (Exception ex)
          {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          }
    }
```

I applied many techniques and solutions but it did not work for me

Your answer would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I edited It. oOption.SelectedFile  has a bytes

Comment: I saw that... deleted my original comment... So what line throws the error exactly? Also, the currentProcess1 doesn't appear to be used for anything (as a side note).

Comment: Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms); this lines gives an error that paramter is not valid

Comment: The byte array is likely not a valid image (cannot be converted so the Image.FromStream is failing).

Comment: ohh Yes you are right .

Comment: this is not a valid image , because when I try to convert jpeg byte to image it successfully run but when I try to convert PDF bytes than it will give error of Parameter not Valid

Comment: Yes, it must be a recognized image format for Image.FromStream to work. If you are trying to convert a pdf you'll have to do it another way. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712557/image-fromstream-parameter-not-valid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
    Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(byteArrayIn);

    return img;
}
```

Comment: No , It doesn`t Work . my bytes are 1120135

Comment: like this byte[] array =
 {
     68,
     111,
     116,
     32,
     78,
     101,
     116,
     32,
     80,
     101,
     114,
     108,
     115
 };

Comment: Actually my byte are generated from dialog Box , so how can i write here , first i select image from dialog box and than pass that image bytes into this method

Comment: Omg. This saved me. I had already spent a couple hours with the old `parameter is not valid` exception. I was using the `Image.FromStream` method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457370/c-how-to-convert-bitmap-byte-array-to-jpeg-format

Answer (score 7):

After trying many things I found a way which has a little bit more control.
In this example you can specify the pixel format and copy the bytes to a Bitmap.

```
byte[] buffer = GetImageBytes();
var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var bitmap_data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, bitmap_data.Scan0, buffer.Length);
bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmap_data);
var result = bitmap as Image;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cmd.CommandText="SELECT * FROM `form_backimg` WHERE ACTIVE=1";

MySqlDataReader reader6= cmd.ExecuteReader();

if(reader6.Read())
{
   code4 = (byte[])reader6["BACK_IMG"];   //BLOB FIELD NAME BACK_IMG
}
reader6.Close();

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(code4);   //code4 is a public byte[] defined on top                             
pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because, you are bringing it incorrectly from database. Try changing your code like this:

```
while (registry.Read())
{
   byte[] image = (byte[])registry["Image"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I got the error since my base64 string had wrong encoding before calling Image.FromStream.
This worked for me in the end:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64ImageString);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    image.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try this,

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     Image returnImage = null;
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))    
     {   
         returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);     
     }
     return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: Hi Umair, I think your byte[] value is not in correct format. do one think, for checking take one image convert to byte[] after that pass this byte value to above coding. If it's converting correct image mean's the problem in your byte value. Let's know..

Comment: having the same issue when downloading an image from S3. However, when using the file before uploading (after submited using a form) it works without an issue. Still can't figure this out