# Load image in PictureBox of Winform C# from SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 r2 database and Winform C# 2010.
In my table I am able to save image from Winform. But when I tried to view this image, there was an error showing.

Table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Image](
    [ID] [char](7) NOT NULL,
    [Photo] [image] NULL)
```

and data in this table is
[image]

I am trying to show this photo in piturebox by using bellow code

```
SqlConnection con;
SqlDataAdapter adapter;
DataSet ds; int rno = 0;
MemoryStream ms;
byte[] photo_aray;

con = new SqlConnection("user id=sa;password=123;database=dbTest");
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select [ID],[Photo] from [tbl_Image] WHERE [ID]='0321253'", con);
adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
ds = new DataSet(); adapter.Fill(ds, "student");

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            pictureBox2.Image = null;
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][4] != System.DBNull.Value)
            {
                photo_aray = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[rno][1];
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo_aray);
                pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No Records");
```

but it is giving error 
"Parameter is not valid." 
in the line 
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667818/error-parameter-is-not-valid-while-converting-bytes-into-image

Comment: How do you store the image to the database?  Show that code.