# How to retrieve blob image in mysql to datagridview using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, blob

I am using this syntax where the dr.getValue(6) is the blob image from mysql.

```
public void LoadRecords()
{
    metroGrid1.Rows.Clear();
    cm = new MySqlCommand("Select * from tblaccnt", cn);

    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        metroGrid1.Rows.Add(dr.GetValue(0), dr.GetValue(1), dr.GetValue(2), dr.GetValue(3), dr.GetValue(4), dr.GetValue(5), dr.GetValue(6));

    }

    dr.Close();
}
```

But I always end up with Parameter is not valid Exception. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have to set byte array for your image

```
  (byte[])reader["ImageData"]
```

And then convert to Image

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])reader["ImageData"]);
 Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: I still got Parameter not valid at the Image.FromStream(ms);

Comment: try this approuch for converting your byte array http://stackoverflow.com/a/17668083/2470530