# Taking OLE (bitmap) object form MS Access database in Visual studio C# , What's wrong in my code?

Tags: c#, debugging, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, bitmap

I am trying to fetch an image from MS Access DB. Data is fetched correctly but when I'm trying to display some error is showing.
My code for display the image is,

```
            ...
            byte[] photoBytes = (byte[])res[11];
            var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(photoBytes);
            image.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
            ...
```

Error : *Additional information: Parameter is not valid.*
[image]

Can anyone tell me where is the error, or probability of error?

my function is

```
public OleDbDataReader studentInfo(String adm_no)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE adm_no = '"+adm_no+"'", con);
        OleDbDataReader res = command.ExecuteReader();
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code, especially when they are **low resolution** and _unreadable_

Comment: Is the field an Ole object or an attachment? Could you post a sample database somewhere? Also, have you seen that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864092/extracting-files-from-an-attachment-field-in-an-access-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can remember OLE's are beasts. If you know for sure what the datatype is you have some chances if you check the binary structure of it. OLE is a container so it's IMO never just the pure content.

I don't have the code anymore but I remember fishing in the hexdumps of the OLE's of different types (Excel, Word, Textfiles, Images, ...) and ending up with a success rate of maybe 80%. If that was because of the types we decided to support or my very restricted knowledge on the inner structure of OLE's I can't tell anymore.

My recommendation for debugging would be to make absolutely sure you have the raw bitmap data before dealing with the binary data at all:

My approach was to create a small object (in this case a bitmap), store it in the DB, get the BLOB of it and lookup the known pattern in there. I remember I found some structures - like the byte size of the searches object - by reverse- engineering and a somewhat stable offset towards the start of the data.

If you, however, happen to know - or even better - *have* the exact structure and implementation of an OLE- object and are able to deal with it, I am absolutely confident you'll manage to also store it and open it as a bitmap.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457370/c-how-to-convert-bitmap-byte-array-to-jpeg-format) for an example of what you are trying to do, although that example is for a JPEG not a Bitmap.  Since you have a `byte[]`, you will need to do something like this for conversion:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
{
  Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: you mean like that

Comment: byte[] photoBytes = (byte[])res[11];
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photoBytes))
                {
                    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
                    image.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
                }

Comment: Give that a try and see how it goes.  If not, you might get away with just doing `image.Image = img` since you already have a Bitmap object.

Comment: i think the problem with "MemoryStream(photoBytes)" code. as i see in compile.,, bcoz image.Image=img also showing error. the error shows till when i comment MemoryStream(photoBytes) sentance

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the `byte[]` variable.  For whatever reason there is an issue getting a `MemoryStream` object from `photoBytes`.

Comment: can you give me a batter reference for ms access OLE database

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your byte stream. Normally I'd say to check whether the `MemoryStream`'s `.Position` is set to 0 before passing it into the `Bitmap` constructor - if it's at the end of the stream, it's possible that you're effectively passing an empty stream - but that shouldn't be the case here.

There are a few places in the constructor where an argument exception would get thrown, but `InvaildParameter` should be related to something being wrong with the byte stream that you're retrieving.  See here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,cbbb65af7f6fafdb,references

And here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/Gdiplus.cs,4edcade52d698713

You should validate that your byte stream is a suitable format for GDI+ to be able to load as an image - try writing the bytes out to a file for example and opening it in Paint.